# What would be the outcome of evaluating the following statements? {javascript}

Tags: javascript, html, dom

> hi guys i am very new to javascript and programming in general. i am studying for a test and i am stuck on this javascript question.
>
> What would be the outcome(including the data type) of evaluating the following statements? are they equivalent?

```
Element.getAttribute("src")
Element.src
```

Comment: Hi Kate, why don't you try evaluating the statements, e.g. in Chrome or Firebug's developer console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what `Element` is and whether `getAttribute` is defined for it. If so, the question is: what does `getAttribute` do, if called with the parameter of `"src"`. For instance, if `getAttribute` is like this:

```
function MyElement() {

    var that = this;
    var getAttribute = function(param) {
        return that.param;
    }
}
```

and `Element` is an instance of `MyElement`, then the answer is yes, unless `getAttribute` was overriden since instantiation.